# Moving to previous row in datagridview

Tags: vb.net

I have wrote code in vb.net to move to the previous row in datagridview when it reaches to first record and when I click again it generates an "index is out of range" error.

```
Dim i As Integer = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index - 1

Me.DataGridView1.CurrentCell = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0)
Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Selected = True
```

Comment: Add a line after `Dim i As Integer = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index - 1` The line is ` If i < 0 Then i = 0`

Comment: Still facing the same problem, when i used that instruction that you have given it directly moves the else part which is 'no more rows'.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim i As Integer = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index - 1
    If i < 0 Then i = 0
    DataGridView1.CurrentCell = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0)
    DataGridView1.Rows(i).Selected = True
End Sub
```

Works for me without error.