# DataGridView in VB.NET shows same record over and over

Tags: database, vb.net, datagridview

I'm using code to connect to an oledb database (Access) then trying to populate a Datagridview with the records.  My code returns the correct number of records but the datagridview populates with the first record over and over. Why? The MoveNext() routine works perfectly well if I populate a combo box with a single field (e.g. Surname).
Here is the code I am using.

clsOpenTable

Public Shared Sub G_OpenConnectionToTable(TableSource As String)

```
    G_sRS.Clear()
    da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(TableSource, ClsConnectToDb.Conn)
    da.Fill(G_sRS, tblSource)
    MaxRows = G_sRS.Tables(tblSource).Rows.Count
    inc = 0

End Sub
```

Body -

tblSource = "LoanItems"

```
    G_OpenConnectionToTable("SELECT LoanItems.* From LoanItems WHERE (((LoanItems.EmployeeId) = " & LblID.Text & "));")

    DataGridView1.ColumnCount = 6
    DataGridView1.Columns(0).Name = "Item"
    DataGridView1.Columns(1).Name = "Serial #"
    DataGridView1.Columns(2).Name = "IMEI #"
    DataGridView1.Columns(3).Name = "Tel #"
    DataGridView1.Columns(4).Name = "Asset #"
    DataGridView1.Columns(5).Name = "Date Signed"

    MoveFirst()

    If Not G_sRS.Tables(tblSource).Rows.Count = 0 Then
        With G_sRS.Tables(tblSource).Rows(inc)
            Dim Ssource As String() = New String() { .Item("Description"), .Item("SerialNo"), .Item("IMEINo"), .Item("TelNo"), .Item("AssetNo"), .Item("DateSigned")}

            While Not inc = MaxRows
                DataGridView1.Rows.Add(Ssource)
                MoveNext()
                Ssource = New String() { .Item("Description"), .Item("SerialNo"), .Item("IMEINo"), .Item("TelNo"), .Item("AssetNo"), .Item("DateSigned")}
            End While
        End With
    End If
```

Modules -

Public Sub MoveFirst()

```
    If inc <> 0 Then
        inc = 0
    End If

End Sub
```

Public Sub MoveNext()

```
    If inc <> MaxRows - 1 Then
        inc = inc + 1
    Else
        inc = MaxRows
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Your `G_OpenConnectionToTable` method should simply return a DataTable, then assign that object to the DataGridview's DataSource Property; e.g., `DataGridView1.DataSoure = G_OpenConnectionToTable()`. You can assign the `HeaderText` of the generated Columns after -- If you need to move the current Row back and forth using dedicated Controls or with any other means, see here: [How to cycle continuously through DataGridView rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69198814/7444103)

Comment: Don't need to go backwards and forward through the datagrid records.  Just need to display the records correctly.  As I said in my post, the G_OpenConnectionToTable works perfectly well when retrieving records and populating a combo box, it just fails in this instance when populating the datagridview control.

Comment: Although what Jimi says is 100% true, and a much more clean and maintainable solution you're actual issue is you're setting up Ssource outside the loop

Comment: That's a convoluted and not exactly useful way to present the data in the UI. Invest some time learning about DataBindings, it will make you life much easier. -- If the DataTable is used by other Controls, use one or more BindingSource objects (depending on the relation between these Controls) as mediators, as shown in the example.

Comment: Thanks guys, I am new to VB.NET so I will look at databindings.  
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `tblSource` is a `DataTable`, you simply have to assign it to the `.DataSource` property of the `DataGridView`. There's no need to write custom code. You can, however, add custom code to hide columns, rename column headers, etc. if need be.

```
' Ensure tblSource is loaded from the data source first.
With DataGridView1
    .DataSource = tblSource
    .Columns(0).HeaderText = "Item"
    .Columns(1).HeaderText = "Serial #"
    ' etc.
End With
```

Comment: Thanks for that, HardCode.  I have managed to sort this problem out and all the code is now working.